# Working with indefinite number of canvas objects

Tags: tkinter, tags, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to make some kind of drawing tool that draws predefined shapes such as line, box etc on tkinter.

**PROBLEM1:** I want to add redo-undo buttons such that when I undo, the last object will be removed and redo, the last object will be added. I thought I can tag each object when created and store every object's tags in a list, but I couldn't get a reasonable solution.

**PROBLEM2:** How will I be able to add the last deleted object? If I delete by tag -undoing event-, the data is lost as far as I know. I shouldn't be losing data I guess.

A sample of pseudo-code below:

```
line=create_line(...)
...
#tag should be assigned for further access
...
stack.append(tag)
...
#deleting by tag in undo event
undo(event): stack.pop()

#adding by tag in redo event
redo(event):
    stack.append(lasttag)
    #problem2: adding the last object
```

I didn't want to draw all borders, but for the sake of clarity, I added these lines. Suggested solutions may be in a larger, more flexible context as long as they answer the question. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution would be to move deleted items to an invisible portion of the canvas instead of deleting them. Then, the "redo" simply moves them back.

The other option is that when you delete something, you save all of its parameters (coordinates, colors, etc) so that you can recreate them later.